# Camel ignores custom Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: json, apache-camel

I am trying to replace the standard Jackson as it is described here: http://camel.apache.org/json.html

I am using the following configuration

```
<bean name="myJsonObjectMapper" class="com.my.app.MyJsonObjectMapper" primary="true"/>

<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
    <camel:template id="camelTemplate"/>
    <camel:dataFormats>
        <camel:json id="json" library="Jackson" objectMapper="myJsonObjectMapper"/>
    </camel:dataFormats>
</camel:camelContext>
```

MyJsonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper. I can see it in Spring context, I can autowire and use it. I see that Camel context is started OK, I am using the Camel version 2.20 where this feature is enabled and fixed. However when I am trying to parse JSON I am getting the exceptions which will non-modified ObjectMapper generate.

When debugging I see that JacksonDataFormat is not initialized with customized ObjectMapper but rather creates a new one on doStart() method.

What am I missing on the Camel configuration?

**UPD:**
I am using that mapper in scope of Camel REST DSL routes in one of the following ways:

```
    restConfiguration().component("servlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest("/somepath")
            .description("blah")
            .post("/subpath/")
            .type(MyRQ.class)
            .outType(MyRS.class)
            .route().id("under-test")
            .bean(service)
            .endRest();
```

or

```
    restConfiguration().component("servlet");

    rest("/somepath")
            .description("blah")
            .post("/subpath/")
            .route().id("under-test")
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .bean(service)
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .endRest();
```

In both cases I am getting the marshaller error due to the usage of the default marshaller instead of custom one. The routes seem to be started in scpe of the correct context, the same I am configuring ObjectMapper for.

Comment: Please add the route in which you're trying to parse your JSON message.

Comment: Can you try with 2.20.1 release.

Comment: I added an unit test to try to reproduce this issue but it works on Camel master: https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/c1ec73135b2b9f17f78d896a0f35204c2dbe0ba0

Comment: @ClausIbsen, I am using REST DSL routes, see the update on the main post.

Comment: Ha then you should have created your question from the start like that. You need to configure the rest-dsl to specify the custom object mapper using the data format properties. The Rest DSL doc has some details

Comment: @ClausIbsen, I think your answer got truncated. What specific options do you refer in [Rest DSL doc](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html)? The only one I see that could fit is `jsonDataFormat`, but the doc clearly states: _**Important:** This option is only for setting a custom name of the data format, not to refer to an existing data format instance._ Could you specify which options did you mean?

Comment: See the `dataFormatProperty`

Comment: @ClausIbsen, I am still not quite following. I am trying to use custom ObjectMapper. In my case playing with mapper properties does not really help. I see that `dataFormatProperty` has a note: _the options value can use the # notation to refer to a bean to lookup in the Registry._ However I do not understand what should be the key if I want to replace the ObjectMapper (if it is even possible). I have tried to look for this bean option usage samples in the Camel codebase, but had no luck there.